# Keep some lines of code private in a public GitHub repository

Tags: php, git, github

I am currently developing a kind of small web-application which I would like to put on GitHub in a public repository. I want to do this to make it open source but I would also like to use the advantages of git while developing it. Now since I am using PHP and MySQL to develop it I sometimes have a line in my code where I create a new object of the class $PDO in which I also have to write my username and password for my MySQL database. Now I would like to know if there is a way to still upload my scripts to GitHub and to also use Git while keeping those lines private.
Have a nice day.

Comment: Your credentials should be stored in one file which should be ignored by git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to only version control part of a file, however, you can only version control specific files using the `.gitignore`

For example file structure:

```
-- .gitignore
-- password.txt
-- script.py
```

And inside the `.gitignore` file:

```
password.txt
```

This will make is so git does not add the password file to github & you can safely store you information in it!

Answer (score 0):

Place your credentials in a separate file and add this file to .gitignore

See https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore